# Error al instalar dependencia jsonwebtoken

Tags: nodejs

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola chicos estoy teniendo un este problema al intentar instalar jsonwebtoken en la carpeta de mi proyecto y me salta este error y solo es con esta todas las otras si logro instalarla con éxito, estoy en la versión 10 de node, gracias!

Comment: Puedes agregar el texto en vez de imagen, y agregar el error que te dice el archivo .log que te dice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es un problema de caché de npm, ejecuta `npm cache clean --force` y vas a poder instalarlo sin problema